# speed up UPDATE operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlconnection, executenonquery

Please help me speed up UPDATE operation on the table.
Table has on unique id, which used to find record and UPDATE its fields.
There are 1M records in the table. No index used. Only unique id.
Insertion takes some time.. where I expected milliseconds.

Table Structure:

```
create table customers
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    phonenum varchar(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    date datetime,
    company varchar(150),
    full_name varchar(150),
    address varchar(150),   
    street varchar(100),
    zip varchar(100),
    city varchar(100),
    info varchar(300),
    op_data varchar(150),
    op_date datetime,
    op_user_taken varchar(100),
    op_time_taken  datetime,
    op_status varchar(100),
    user_taken varchar(100),
    time_taken  datetime,
    status varchar(100),        
    );
```

I'm using SqlConnection System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection and ExecuteNonQuery method to UPDATE record.

Does my table need redesigned or ExecuteNonQuery is so slow?

EDIT: Update command:

```
"UPDATE customers SET user_taken=@param1, time_taken=@param2,
 date=@param3, company=@param4, full_name=@param55,
 address=@param6, street=@param8, zip=@param9,
 city=@param10, info=@param11 , status=\'Completed\',
op_data=@param12 WHERE id=@param7";
```

Comment: Can we see an UPDATE statement example?

Comment: Show us your update statement. If you are updating all 1M rows, then yes, it will take some time.

Comment: If you expect it to happen in milliseconds then add some Indexes? If it has to do a full table scan in a table of 1 million records then don't expect it to be fast. :p

Comment: No, for sure. First it takes "free" record, lock it. And then Updates it, knowing its ID. Not all 1M records. Only one record is updated per operation.

Comment: If you do not have an index on the table it still has to scan the entire table to find the record that it needs to update. Add an index.

Comment: What is the datatype of `@param7` and what does the execution plan look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your id column a primary key.  Primary keys automatically become an index.  If you are running a simple update statement such as:

```
UPDATE customers SET <something> WHERE id = @id
```

Then this should run an INDEX SEEK and be much faster.  Without that index you are updating with a TABLE SCAN which takes orders of magnitude longer than an INDEX SEEK or even an INDEX SCAN (which would occur if you are updating large amounts of rows).

Another trick is to take your update statement and run it in SQL Server and look at the Execution Plan.  This will tell you where the bottleneck is.  Also, you can go to Query Options | Advanced | and set statistics to display in the output tab.

Comment: Totally agree, that's what indexes are for.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` are both constraints and indexes!

Comment: Yes, but a UNIQUE constraint cannot be made clustered.  He would need to also add a clustered index on top of the UNIQUE constraint to achieve a better index for large amounts of data.

Comment: Not true that it can't be made clustered. `CREATE TABLE customers(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) UNIQUE CLUSTERED NOT NULL)` is perfectly valid. The DDL posted will be able to use the NCI implicitly created by the unique constraint and then do a bookmark lookup to find the row to update. Not great but not catastrophic either.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't have clustered index (`unique` is nonclustered by default), so SQL Server uses Nonclustered Index on a Heap to locate your record for updating(`UNIQUE` is an index ). `Id` should be a primary key (which is clustered by default), not `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score -2):

Try -

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("update sql", conn))
{
      SqlDataReader results = (SqlDataReader)comm.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Just curious...

Comment: Why ExecuteReader() to run an UPDATE command? Can you explain why you think this approach will be faster?